# Does the standard mandate enable_shared_from_this is to be inherited publicly? Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, libstdc++, libc++

It's common to inherit from `enable_shared_from_this` just to be able to return `shared_ptr`'s from member functions as the primary intention, with no intention of exposing `enable_shared_from_this` API in the derived class.

Since to make use of `enable_shared_from_this` one must do so through public inheritance (does the standard mandates this? what's the rationale?), this can't be achieved and `enable_shared_from_this` API is forced into derived class public API.

Inherenting `enable_shared_from_this` privately and making `shared_ptr` a friend class do work on clang coupled with libc++, but doesn't work with stdlibc++.

Since `private enable_shared_from_this` + `friend shared_ptr` (or protected inheritance) seems to cover this use case, shouldn't it be sufficient by the standard for fitting as a solution for the "shared from this" problem?

Comment: You could try inheriting `protected`, i.e. `class T : protected std::enable_shared_from_this<T> { ... };` ? I didn't try it myself

Comment: @ChrisBeck ok thanks. I guess the question still holds though, if one doesn't wish to do even that (`protected`).

Comment: I think that there's no way the `shared_from_this` mechanism can work if the inheritance is totally private. The way it works, if I understand right, is that the control structure for the `shared_ptr` (the reference count) is stored in a prefix in your class, so like, there is some data member in `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>`. In order to make a `shared_ptr` from `this`, it needs to be able to static cast `this` and find the ref counter. Also `std::make_shared` need to be able to detect things like this in your type. If the inheritance is private then I guess they can't do that. Not sure..

Comment: @ChrisBeck that's the reason I mention being friend of `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Ok, but then you might need to friend `std::make_shared` and `std::weak_ptr` and other things potentially

Comment: You know, this is a pretty good question, I guess I don't see a good reason that `shared_from_this()` is not standardized as a protected member of `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Then if you want to expose it publicly you can put a `using` declaration. That's easier than all this friend stuff.

Comment: @ChrisBeck good. For me it's a better design but it would be a breaking change applied now :-/

Answer (score 3):

> Since `private enable_shared_from_this` + friend `shared_ptr` seems to cover this use case, shouldn't it be sufficient by the standard?

No. The standard permits implementations wide latitude with how they implement things. The constructor of `shared_ptr<T>` that adopts an object may defer the shared-from-this stuff to some helper function or other object. For maximum irony, it could defer to a base class of `shared_ptr<T>` ;)

As such, `enable_shared_from_this` must be accessible by any code in order for the `shared_ptr` constructor to work.

Comment: Looks like a tradeoff, allowing wide latitude implementations in detriment of every user's public API vs constraining it lightly for sake of the user API options

Comment: @pepper_chico: You'll have to get in line behind everyone trying to get function pointers/member pointers to standard library functions.

Comment: So, why doesn't `enable_shared_from_this<T>` force that it's a public base class of `T`, that is, `T*` is convertible to `enable_shared_from_this<T>*`? I could imagine a compile-time error when that fails..

Comment: @lorro: Because you can't actually do that. At the time when `enable_shared_from_this<T>` is being instantiated with a particular `T`, that particular `T` is *incomplete*. After all, `T` is derived from `enable_shared_from_this<T>`, right? So when this is being instantiated, the only thing the compiler knows about `T` is that the name exists. The member functions of `enable_shared_from_this` can access `T`'s definition because of how C++ specifies how inline member functions work. But those rules only work for members; you can't static_assert on a property of `T` in the class itself.

Comment: @NicolBolas: http://ideone.com/cpzAhH : remove comments around `private` to see the error msg.

Comment: @NicolBolas Note that an incomplete class type can still be a derived type: in the definition of the derived class, it is already a derived type during the definition of members.